# Array Find or Filter based on multiple condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I have list of data with different data as follows

```
[0: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Allocate", pairStatus: 1, …}
1: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission", pairStatus: 1, …}
2: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Aggregate", pairStatus: 1, …}
3: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1, …}
4: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1, …}
5: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1, …}
6: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Receive", pairStatus: 1, …}
7: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Receive", pairStatus: 1, …}]
```

I need output as follows - Group lat and lan with title

```
[0: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Allocate,Commission,Aggregate"}
1: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship,Ship,Ship,Receive,Receive"}]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you have tried to create this grouping? Are you using any third party libraries like lodash to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this. Find elements in the accumulator, if an item already exists in the accumulator having the same latitude and longitude then concatenate the title into the existing item.

If item doesn't exist, push a new item into the accumulator having "lat", "lng" and "title" properties

```js
let rawData = [  {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Allocate", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Aggregate", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Receive", pairStatus: 1},
{lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Receive", pairStatus: 1}]

let finalData = rawData.reduce((acc, {lat, lng, title}) => {
  let found = acc.find((e) => {
    return lat === e.lat && lng === e.lng
  })
  
  if (found) {
     found.title = `${found.title},${title}`
  }
  else {
    acc.push({lat, lng, title})
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(finalData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly as expected